# Get values on outer ng-repeat object by key from inner ng-repeat array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
people{
obj1:{
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3,
      key4:value4,
      key5:value5
 }
obj2:{
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3,
      key4:value4,
      key5:value5
 }
obj3:{
    key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3,
      key4:value4,
      key5:value5
 }
 obj4:{
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3,
      key4:value4,
      key5:value5
 }
obj5:{
key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3,
      key4:value4,
      key5:value5
 }
obj6:{
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3,
      key4:value4,
      key5:value5
 }
}

keys_array=[key1,key3,key5];

<div ng-repeat="people in peoples" >
   <hr />
   <table style="width:100%">
      <tr ng-repeat="key in keys">
         <td>{{key}}:</td><td >{{device.key}}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <hr />
 </div>
```

Here I am trying to get value of outer `ng-repeat` loop object by key from inner `ng-repeat` loop array.
I don't know which is right way for this.

Comment: Do you get the attempted result ? *keys* and *people* don't exist as array in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code had errors (variable names, syntax).
I have solved the bugs and modified the html so that it was easier to edit

Controller:

```
$scope.peoples = {
    obj1:{
          key1:'value1',
          key2:'value2',
          key3:'value3',
          key4:'value4',
          key5:'value5'
     },
    obj2:{
          key1:'value1',
          key2:'value2',
          key3:'value3',
          key4:'value4',
          key5:'value5'
     },
    obj3:{
        key1:'value1',
          key2:'value2',
          key3:'value3',
          key4:'value4',
          key5:'value5'
     },
     obj4:{
          key1:'value1',
          key2:'value2',
          key3:'value3',
          key4:'value4',
          key5:'value5'
     },
    obj5:{
    key1:'value1',
          key2:'value2',
          key3:'value3',
          key4:'value4',
          key5:'value5'
     },
    obj6:{
          key1:'value1',
          key2:'value2',
          key3:'value3',
          key4:'value4',
          key5:'value5'
     }    
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples" >
     {{people}}
      <span ng-repeat="key in keys_array">
         {{people[key]}}
      </span>
 </div>
```